# St. Beatle's Blues

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, geography

Can you identify where these peculiarly named places are located?

> 1. Ableis
> 2. Askera
> 3. Handleama
> 4. Offington
> 5. Speechtown
> 6. St. Beatle's

Looking for names of countries.

Hint:

> An alternative clue for #6 is "St. King's", which arguably fits better with the overall theme.

Hint #2:

> Two answers per line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Continuing from where Gareth left off:

> Parts of the peculiar names can be replaced. The replacement and the replaced parts together form a new word or expression.

... and paying heed to the second hint:

> There are two answers for each line

... the following countries are found:

> **Able**is
>  France, **Par**is (*parable*)
>  Tunisia, **Tun**is (*tunable*)
>
>  As**ker**a
>  Eritrea, As**mar**a (*marker*)
>  Kazakhstan, As**tan**a (*tanker*)
>
>  **Handle**ama
>  Bahrain, **Man**ama (*manhandle*)
>  Panama, **Pan**ama (*panhandle*)
>
>  **Off**ington
>  US, **Wash**ington (*wash off*)
>  New Zealand, **Well**ington (*well off*)
>
>  **Speech**town
>  Sierra Leone, **Free**town (*free speech*)
>  St. Vincent and the Greadines, **Kings**town (*King's Speech*)
>
>  St **Beatle**'s
>  Grenada, St. **George**'s (*Beatle Gerorge Harrison*)
>  Antigua and Barbuda, St. **John**'s (*Beatle John Lennon*)

Comment: Excellent! I'm feeling very dim now...

Comment: Then you know how I felt when I read your answer this morning. `:)` (I couldn't find Ableis or Askera and thought Offington a bit weak. Then I got sidetracked when I found that there is a Handleama in the Florida panhandle.)

Answer (score 6):

**Partial answer**

Several of these are

> national capitals in which a word has been replaced by something that can follow it to make a single word or a reasonably common phrase.

However,

> I haven't been able to make either Askera or St Beatle's fit that pattern, though there are some obvious candidates for St Beatle's if we're allowed to stretch a bit.

Ableis

> PARIS (parable), capital of France

Askera

> I haven't been able to make this one work.

Handleama

> MANAMA (manhandle), capital of Bahrain

Offington

> WASHINGTON (wash off), capital of the USA

Speechtown

> FREETOWN (free speech), capital of Sierra Leone

St Beatle's

> This doesn't quite seem to fit the pattern; best I can do is ST GEORGE'S (George Harrison, one of the Beatles), capital of Grenada, or ST JOHN'S (John Lennon, one of the Beatles), capital of Antigua and Barbuda.

Comment: You're right that the last one is a bit of a looser fit than the others. (It was "St. King's" originally, but I just couldn't pass the opportunity for the Beatle reference.)

Comment: Whether King or Beatle, it seems to be ambiguous. And I'm still drawing a blank on Askera...

Comment: Oh, you're far from done :) On the right track, though.